# flutter: Because pedometer depends on pedometer, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, pedometer

I just create a new project and run the command "flutter pub add pedometer" in the terminal and that error occurs.how can I fix this?

Comment: can you show the exact error?

Comment: The caption does not make any sense unless you edit the question and paste the pubspec.yaml

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.